# Pause a sub while allowing user to operate a different sub

Tags: vb.net

Hi im trying to create a windows media player type application, specifically the back button. It needs to on the first click set the song back to the start, and if clicked again within 2 seconds change the song back to the one before it.

To do this i have overlapped 2 seperate buttons with 2 seperate procedures, i want the first button to hide for 2 seconds once clicked, and then show after those 2 seconds. ALthough iv found ways to temporarily suspend the program, it doesnt allow me to click to button behind to activate its features. This is the test code i came up with, any help appreciated-

```
Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
    PictureBox5.Visible = False
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    PictureBox5.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
    MsgBox("Success")
End Sub
```

Comment: You’re approaching the problem from the wrong direction. Use a single button, and have different events handlers for the `Click` and `DoubleClick` events. The alternative is *much harder* and requires multithreading (although using a `BackgroundWorker` will simplify it somewhat).

Comment: You don't need two `Buttons`. Just use one. When you click it the first time, set a field to an appropriate value, e.g. a `DateTime` field to the current time. When it's clicked again, you can test that field to see whether the elapsed time is less than 2 seconds and then act accordingly.

Comment: Calling `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` will just lock up the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a little [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/async)/[await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator) magic.  With this combination, the button underneath will be responsive during the two second period:

```
Private Async Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
    PictureBox5.Visible = False
    Await Task.Delay(2000)
    PictureBox5.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Notice the `Async` after `Private` in the event handler signature!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var clicks =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern(h => button.Click += h, h => button.Click -= h)
        .Select(ep => Unit.Default);

IObservable<string> query =
    clicks
        .Timestamp()
        .StartWith(Timestamped.Create(Unit.Default, DateTimeOffset.MinValue))
        .Publish(cs =>
            cs.Zip(cs.Skip(1), (c0, c1) =>
                c1.Timestamp.Subtract(c0.Timestamp).TotalSeconds >= 2.0
                    ? "Restart" 
                    : "Previous"));

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            if (x == "Restart")
            {
                // Do Restart
            }
            else
            {
                // Do Previous
            }
        });
```

I understand that this is not as simple as just doing `Await Task.Delay(2000)`, but the power of Rx is immense and worth learning.