# VB.Net alternatvie for Threading.thread.sleep used in a RS232 application

Tags: vb.net, ascii

I'm busy with software that uses Rs232 Com port communication module.
I send a roll-call out 1st to all users (Ping all users) and then wait 10 min to receive all the roll-calls back, thereafter I send to all the outstanding names (Ping outstanding active individual) using a listview with the remaining members names, I send all the outstanding names in burst of 3's with 3.5 sec in-between. I'm using `Threading.Thread.Sleep()` to prevent flooding my repeater.
Is there an alternative to `Threading.Thread.Sleep()` that allows the software to still receive roll-call feedbacks sending the roll-Call pings through the Rs232 Module?

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To LsvCopyRemove.Items.Count - 1
        If LsvCopyRemove.Items(i).SubItems(11).Text = "Yes" Then
            Dim Group As String = LsvCopyRemove.Items(i).Text
            StringData = vbCrLf & "MY String Information comes here"
            _rs232.Write("" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            _rs232.Write(StringData & vbCrLf) 'The text contained in the txtText will be sent to the serial port as ascii
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500)
            _rs232.Write(StringData & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500)
            _rs232.Write(StringData & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(3500)
            Me.rtbTX.AppendText(.Text & vbCr)

            '***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
            .Text = String.Empty & vbCrLf
            Data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(.Text)
            _rs232.SendData(Data)
            '***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(6500)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative?  What is your concern with your current strategy?

Comment: Assuming WinForms, add `async` to the method signature and use `await Task.Delay(...)` as in [this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54945458/2330053).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is asynchronous programming, which allows you to execute multiple threads simultaneously. In your example, you'll have to execute the code above which sends the outstanding names in a seperate thread. There are two ways to accomplish this:

Using System.Threading: Put the code you want to execute in a seperate thread in a sub routine, then call it like this:

```
Dim newThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf myFunction)
newThread.Start()
```

Now the code in the function called myFunction is executed, but the execution of the current function is continued, which allows you to still receive events.

You can also use the newer Threading.Tasks namespace, which can be used in a similar way:

```
Dim newTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf myFunction)
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `Task.Run` than `TaskFactory.StartNew`.  In any event, there are certain cases that only the former supports, I'm not sure if there's anything that goes the other way around.